# omnivision cameras

Tags: camera

Could anyone please let me know if the following data sheet is for image sensor or SoC? 
http://www.ovt.com/download_document.php?type=sensor&sensorid=55
In the second page it shows a diagram and it looks like it has image sensor and ISP. But when I contacted nearby vendor they said that they can only find image sensor. And the Omnivision also said they sells image sensor only. But then I don't understand what the data sheet tells.

Answer (score 2):

It's an image sensor. The functional block diagram on page two is showing all of it's, well, functionality! The full datasheet describes all the features represented as the boxes and arrows, and the sensor input and output pins are outside of the box.